# Any relation between visor and supervisor?

Tags: synonyms

I am about to buy a domain name. The domain name represents an application with monitors a computer system. Supervisor or monitor are words that might fit for describing the tool but I wonder if I could just use "visor" in the domain name or will it give a totally different meaning?

An example of domain might be:

computersystemvisor.com

Comment: Requests to help name something are out of scope and may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: See the answers below that speak about the word origins, which are related to seeing/watching.

Comment: Just my opinion, but your example of computersystemvisor would *not* make me think of *supervisor*, but *advisor*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because naming products is off-topic.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

"Visor" has a standalone meaning as a movable part of a helmet, which can be pulled down to cover the face.

The word "supervisor" has spawned the (to me, slightly distasteful, even though I once played drums on a song with it in the lyrics) "hypervisor" (which is like a higher-level supervisor of an operating system), which suggests that "visor" is a suffix.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor

But a suffix of what?  A supervisor doesn't do anything with "supers" and a hypervisor doesn't do anything with "hypers".  So, as a suffix it doesn't really work, as it doesn't really have anything to do with the thing that it comes after.  So, I wouldn't say that it's attained full suffix status yet.

Having said that, I suspect that if you showed the word "computersystemvisor" to a group of people, a lot of them would guess that it means "computer system supervisor", and that it's more of a contraction than anything else.  I don't think many people would interpret it as meaning anything else, anyway: they'd either get it or just not know what you mean at all.

Comment: This really does not speak to the relation between these words at all, which is only a relation of origin (roots). It says nothing at all about the word *visor*, speaking only of its being or not being a suffix. Hard to believe this is the accepted answer, IMO.

Comment: Why appreciated all answers and voted them all up this answer confirmed some thoughts within me and also covered other things interesting to me. So my vote as accepted answer is just my opinion.

Answer (score 22):

They both share a common root with *vision* and *video*, namely the Latin *visio* (seeing, sight, thing seen) which is the noun form of the verb *videre* (to see).

Therefore, A visor is a thing you see through.  A supervisor is a person who looks over something, such as a group of employees, a project, or computer system.

Here's some sources:

- Entymonline entry for [vision](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vision)
- Wiktionary entry for Latin [visio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/visio#Latin)
- Wiktionary entry for Latin [video](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/video#Latin)

Answer (score 6):

"Visor" comes through the French root of "face". The meaning of "Supervisor" is split from that (over, videre) and means "Overseer". Normally concatenated "visor" words relate more to supervisory functions than facial functions.

In the case of your question my own opinion is that the concatenation would make it clear that you're using a supervisory case.